# rest api with space followed by number

Tags: rest, url-encoding

I have to access a rest API and one of the attribute has a space followed by a number. I know that I have to replace spaces by %20 but what if it is followed by a number?

For exemple:

```
http://myapi/ressource?query={user-22[*%203.2.2.0]}
```

Comment: So what is the problem? What result do you get and what is the behavior you expect?

Comment: I get an http error 400 because it doesn't understand %203 It can't understand that what I want is * 3.2.2.0 (an asterix followed by a space followed itself by a number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found finally a way, I used

```
http://myapi/ressource?query=%7Buser-22%5B*%25203.2.2.0%5D%7D
```

The difference is %2520 instead of %20 only

Comment: Then your application is decoding the query parameter twice ("%2520" is a space encoded twice). If you have access to this application, that's probably what you should fix first.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to this application. It the rest API from HP Qualitiy Center. I don't know if you know it

Answer (score 1):

`{}[]` are considered [unsafe characters](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm#whatwhy) so you should escape them too. A valid URL would be:

```
http://myapi/ressource?query=%7Buser-22%5B*%203.2.2.0%5D%7D
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will correct that too. But when I try with [*3.2.2.0] it works. The problem here is the space between * and 3.2.2.0